# [python][selenium] on-screen position of element

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, position, absolute

I would like to know the on-screen position of some element. I know how to get the position of an element in Python Selenium webriver but how to get an offset from the left-top corner of the screen?

[image]

Comment: You need just a length of the line instead of `x`/`y` coordinates, right?

Comment: No, i would like to know know the x,y cords of left-top html page corner that i could add to this result of webdriver.location to get on-screen location of some element.

Answer (score 11):

I guess it's not possible to define distance from top-left corner of browser window to top-level corner of screen with just `selenium`. But you can try to implement following:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window() # now screen top-left corner == browser top-left corner 
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions")
question = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Questions")
y_relative_coord = question.location['y']
browser_navigation_panel_height = driver.execute_script('return window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight;')
y_absolute_coord = y_relative_coord + browser_navigation_panel_height
x_absolute_coord = question.location['x']
```

Comment: It only works if the window is maximised. Else there is a 8px margin (left right and bottom) with chrome.

Comment: This does not consider the window position or whether the document has been scrolled. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 11):

There is no way to do this with 100% accuracy, but here is the best workaround that considers the browser window's offset, the toolbars in the window, and the scrolling position of the document:

```
# Assume there is equal amount of browser chrome on the left and right sides of the screen.
canvas_x_offset = driver.execute_script("return window.screenX + (window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth) / 2 - window.scrollX;")
# Assume all the browser chrome is on the top of the screen and none on the bottom.
canvas_y_offset = driver.execute_script("return window.screenY + (window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight) - window.scrollY;")
# Get the element center.
element_location = (element.rect["x"] + canvas_x_offset + element.rect["width"] / 2,
                    element.rect["y"] + canvas_y_offset + element.rect["height"] / 2)
```

Comment: Your solution does not work for the scrolling position.

Comment: @RajatAgrawal I guess it depends on what you are trying to achieve? On the original question, there is a comment saying "i would like to know know the x,y cords of left-top html page corner that i could add to this result of webdriver.location to get on-screen location of some element." That's what I'm solving for. If you just want the distance to the top left corner, ignoring the scroll distance, just remove "- window.scrollX" and "- window.scrollY" from my code.

Comment: I want the coordinates of the element which is down the page(scrolling required) and I need to get the coordinates of that which are relative to the screen( with respect to the screen, not browser). And thanks for replying.

Comment: Your solution worked! But one change needed is that my laptop was running in 200% zoom mode. Needed to change it from the window's settings. So, this is something to take into considartion

Answer (score 1):

The method `get_window_position()` of Selenium webdriver enables you to access the location of your browser with respect to your screen:

```
#Get the current location of your browser 
browser_location = driver.get_window_position()
# eg: {'y': 127, 'x': 15}

# Set the absolute position of your Web element here (top-left corner)
element_location = (element.location["x"]+ browser_location["x"],
                    element.location["y"]+ browser_location["y"])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
page_offset = self.driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset;")
ih = self.driver.execute_script("return window.innerHeight;")
oh = self.driver.execute_script("return window.outerHeight;")
chrome_offset = window_size[1]-ih
ex = pos["x"]+8+element_size["width"]/2
ey = (pos["y"]-page_offset)+chrome_offset-(element_size["height"]/2)
pyautogui.moveTo(ex,ey,2)
```

Comment: what is window_size[1] referring to I am trying to implement this approach in java.