# How to find correct element location in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to find the correct location of an element in selenium but this is givin me some troubles, this is my code

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller as MouseController
mouse = MouseController()

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.maximize_window()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)

driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainbar"]/div[1]/h1')
x, y = element.location["x"], element.location["y"]

mouse.position = x, y
```

But i don't understand why it returns a position different from the correct element location

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  What are your expected element locations?

Comment: The element location that i was expecting was a corner of the writing 'Top Questions' at the link

Comment: Maybe `x, y = element.location["x"]+element.size["width"]/2, element.location["y"]+element.size["height"]/2` ?

Answer (score 0):

Pynput is going to the absolute coordinates based off of the screen size whereas the coordinates you get from selenium are relative to the browser window.

In order to counteract this you need to take the browser navigation bar size into account when calculating the y coordinate:

```
browser_navigation_panel_height = driver.execute_script('return window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight;')
x, y = element.location["x"], element.location["y"] + browser_navigation_panel_height
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42807676/pythonselenium-on-screen-position-of-element) pointed me to a solution.

**NB: This solution will only work when the browser window is maximised**