# How to find position of an element using pyautogui and selenium automatically

Tags: python, selenium, pyautogui

I'm writing an script and I need to find cursor position automatically for an element. The script will run on different computers, so I want it be done automatically.

Suppose I want to click on search box in the head of stackoverflow.com to find its position using `selenium` and `pyautogui`.

How to do that so that mouse is in that position and script is exited?

**Edit 1**

Suppose I want it to click on this element:

> `input` which `name="q"` and `class="s-input s-input__search js-search-field "`

**Edit 2**:

My current code with the help of `Prophet` and `undetected Selenium`, but the output I get is not correct:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import pyautogui
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

path = r'path'
user_data = r'user'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f'--user-data-dir={user_data}')
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=options)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
xpath = '//*[@id="search"]/div/input'

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
driver.get(url)
position = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath))).location_once_scrolled_into_view
# both tried the above position var and the below
# position = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath))).location
# element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
# actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
# position = pyautogui.position()
file = open('position.txt', 'a')
file.write(f'{position}, {datetime.now()}\n')
driver.close()

# to test the exact or relative position to compare with above code
# while True:
#     sleep(1)
#     print(pyautogui.position())
```

**Edit 3**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import pyautogui
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

path = r'D:\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe'
user_data = r'C:\\Users\\Saeed\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f'--user-data-dir={user_data}')
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=options)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
xpath = '//*[@id="search"]/div/input'  # `search` box at header
url = 'https://stackoverflow.com//'
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
sleep(10)
position = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath))).location
print(position)
file = open('position.txt', 'a')
file.write(f'{position}, {datetime.now()}\n')
# pyautogui.click(793, 9)
driver.close()

# while True:
#     sleep(1)
#     print(pyautogui.position())
```

The video how my code now works: https://up.mazandhost.com/uploads/1028407950.bandicam-2022-03-27-21-33-27-729.mp4

**Solution in my case**:

Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56693949/5790653 helps me.

Answer (score 2):

With `Selenium` you can perform mouse actions with the use of `action_chains` library.
Once you locate the element with selenium you can move the mouse to that element as following:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)

element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'the_xpath_locator')
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

Comment: Thanks, but not sure why it does not work perfectly for me (surely works for you fine). It returns the current mouse cursor position (not the position on search box). I did edit the question. Do you please check edit 2?

Comment: Sure. I can't do it right now, but I will take a look in 20-30 minutes

Comment: Can you please clarify: what exactly are you trying to achieve? The location of mouse cursor or Google search input web element? In case you are talking about the former - I can't see you scrolling the web page, so why should the location of the web element change and also if so why / how it is connected with mouse you mentioned in the original question?

Comment: I want to find the location of `Google search input web element` automatically, so when I run this code in another laptop, it clicks on search box (mine, yours, and someone else's laptop should work the same).

Comment: OK, seems that is what undetected Selenium initially gave you. His code prints the location of that element. But why should the location of that element change if you don't scroll the entire web page?

Comment: Do you please check edit 3 and my video?

Comment: I really do appreciate your help and favor. I did edit the question as my question is solved.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, that's really interesting. I'm sorry I could not help you more, was very busy this evening.

Comment: At this moment the mentioned answer helped me. I'll try your answer tomorrow to see what part I was doing wrong with your answer and undetected selenium.

Comment: Sure. In case you need more my assistance please let me know

Answer (score 1):

To extract the *location* and/or *position* an element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using [location](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.location) attribute:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "q"))).location)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  {'x': 439, 'y': 184}
  ```
- Using [location_once_scrolled_into_view](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.location_once_scrolled_into_view) attribute:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "q"))).location_once_scrolled_into_view)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  {'x': 439, 'y': 184}
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### This usecase

As per the HTML details:

> input which name="q" and class="s-input s-input__search js-search-field "

To click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.s-input.s-input__search.js-search-field[name='q']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='s-input s-input__search js-search-field ' and @name='q']"))).click()
  ```

---

### Alternative

As an alternative you can also use the [move_to_element()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70168250/7429447) method from [ActionChains API](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains) as follows:

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='s-input s-input__search js-search-field ' and @name='q']")))).perform()
```

Comment: Thanks, but my output is not correct. It shows `{'x': 474, 'y': 9}`, while it should be about `(x=635, y=94)` in maximized, or `(x=1338, y=104)` in side minimized window. I edited the question. Do you please check that?

Comment: Ideally your screen should be always maximized `options.add_argument("start-maximized")` while executing your tests. The example was of the search field on Google Home Page. Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: With `CSS_SELECTOR`, I get `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified`, but wit `XPATH`, it prints my current mouse position (it's not on search box).

Comment: Fixed the _CSS_SELECTOR_. Well we are not printing the `current mouse position` as that would involve different set of [Mouse actions APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71609969/7429447). We are printing the element identified by the respective [_locator strategies_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over)

Comment: So, is there any way to control mouse to go to that element?

Comment: Updated my previous comment with link to usage of _**Mouse actions APIs**_.

Comment: I use `move_to_element` but mouse position is not changed. Should it change the position physically like when I move my mouse?

Comment: @Saeed I would suggest hold on the idea of using the _**Mouse actions APIs**_, use the `expected_conditions` if that works. Else I will update the answer with another approach.

Comment: Moreover location through _Selenium_ and _pyautogui_ may differ significantly.

Comment: Checkout the answer update.

Comment: Do you please check edit 3 and my video?

Comment: I really do appreciate your help and favor. I did edit the question as my question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it.

```
import pyautogui
from random import *

elementToClick = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR,value='#nav-search-submit-button')

panel_height = driver.execute_script('return window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight;')
abs_x = elementToClick.location['x']
y = elementToClick.location['y']
abs_y = y + panel_height

pyautogui.moveTo(abs_x, abs_y, uniform(0.6, 1.7), pyautogui.easeOutQuad)
pyautogui.click(abs_x, abs_y)
```