# How to get screen coordinate of a element in selenium? [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, resolution, pyautogui

I wanted to know that how can one get the coordinates of a element according to the screen resolution rather than the browser windows size, I have tried this already (code block), but it provides coordinates according to the browser window rather than the screen

```py
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='search_form_input_homepage']")
print(element.location)
```

Any alternatives that I can use?

A terrible attempt to explain what I mean :

**note: driver.execute_script** is not allowed, as the website has a bot blocker :(
[image: This is the visual representation of what im trying to say]

Comment: Similar question: [By Andersson] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42807676/pythonselenium-on-screen-position-of-element)

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to use the exexute_script function due to the website having a bot detector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.size` and `.location` to get the sizes.

Try this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep, strftime

url = "some url"

webdriver = webdriver.Chrome()
webdriver.get(url)


webdriver.fullscreen_window()

cookies = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath("xome xpath")

location = cookies.location
size = cookies.size
w, h = size['width'], size['height']

print(location)
print(size)
print(w, h)
```

Comment: Sorry, As I said already in the question, .location isn't working as the coordinates are based on the browser window rather than the screen

Comment: You can maximise the screen using `webdriver.maximize_window()`

Comment: Doesn't maximize window maximize the window? which will still, Not give correct coordinates as browser has a upper tab menu and there is the taskbar too

Comment: Thx for the answer, worked like a charm with a few tweaks :)

Comment: :) If I may ask, what were the tweaks

Comment: :D You see the concept of the answer is to not use any other commands, and make the browser the size of the entire screen, But they made a small mistake of using maximize window rather than fullscreen_window, So I added that, and it worked like a charm @The Pilot Dude, I am now editing the answer

Comment: Wow. That's a smart idea!

Comment: I can't understand if that was sarcastic or a general comment, I didn't mean to hurt or insult you in anyway :)

Comment: No no no no! I'm being general. That WAS a smart idea (no sarcasm involved :)

Comment: Ah thx :) oh.. i just noticed you are the OP, i just feel dumb now

Answer (score 1):

```
print(element.location_once_scrolled_into_view)
```

Try if this helps , more available methods like size rect etc can be found at:

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement

Comment: one min, lemme try

Comment: Nope, Sorry, The location is still based on the browser window, rather than the screen, and isn't solving the problem

Comment: @CoffeeGuy what you mean by browser window ? means it showing only element within the view port ?

Comment: What I want is that the coordinates of the element, are according to the browser window, For eg. if i have something right at the top of the browser tab, the element location is being shown according to the browser window (0y as it is at the top) rather than the actual location, which should be shown according to the screen

Comment: @CoffeeGuy why would you want that selenium don't have access to screen outside browser

Comment: wdym? I didnt say that selenium shouldnt have access to screen outside browser, One minute, lemme take a screenshot and edit it with paint, to visually represent what im trying to say

Comment: @CoffeeGuy driver.get_window_position() did you try this  ? get the postion and x and y of elem.location to get final

Comment: That gives the window location, not the elements location, which I want